# A tag clickable on the whole row how to disable? except on the link itself?

Tags: html, css

I have a question why using tag `a` I can click the whole row on the right is clickable as well?

on the back row on right side this area is clickable even through there no link any way to remove this clickable area ?

```html
<a id="back-page-btn" class="back-btn d-flex" href="">
  <i data-feather="arrow-left-circle"></i>
  <p class="mx-2 my-auto">Back</p>
</a>
```

I realize this html code I am able to click on the white background on the back row is there a way to only use link to be clickable but not the white background.

Comment: use `label` not `p` inside `a`

Comment: thanks but the right side of the background is clickable

Comment: from back >>>>>>> 
all is clickable anyway where only the href tag is the only clickable ?

Comment: nvm i fix by removing the class and puting the label 
    <a id="back-page-btn" class="back-btn" href="manageUsers_api.html"><i data-feather="arrow-left-circle"></i>
      <label style="cursor: pointer;"class="mx-2 my-auto">Back</label></a>

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix was remove d-flex class and change as using p to label to wrap it up with /a

```
<a id="back-page-btn" class="back-btn" href="manageUsers_api.html"><i data-feather="arrow-left-circle"></i>
<label style="cursor: pointer;"class="mx-2 my-auto">Back</label></a>
```